# Multiple Blazor Server Apps and Azure Authentication Logout Issue

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0, blazor-server-side

I have 2 Blazor server-side apps, each with their own app registration in Azure AD. They're pretty much out-of-the-box from creating a new Blazor Server-Side app in VS2019, .NET Core 3.0.

When they are open in 2 tabs of a browser and I log out of App A I am still able to navigate the page links in App B. App B does not see that I have logged out until I press the browser's page refresh button.

I have tried adding @attribute [Authorize] to the pages, defining `<NotAuthorized>` in the App.razor page, and using the `AuthenticationStateProvider` in the page `OnInitializedAsync` function to check if `.IsAuthenticated` with no luck.

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@attribute [Authorize]    

[CascadingParameter] Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Error");
        }
    }
```

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <h1>Please Log In.</h1>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <CascadingAuthenticationState>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </CascadingAuthenticationState>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options => { options.DetailedErrors = true; });
            services.AddSingleton<TestContextService>();
        }
```

Comment: 1) Does this happen with Web Browsers other than Google Chrome (the latest one has issues logging out due to a same site cookie issue) 2) Does this happen in Production or just on localhost?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - this is deployed to a web server on our intranet. I'll check with another browser other than Chrome. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: It does in fact work as expected in Edge and IE. I'll have to research if there is a fix for Chrome. Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably related to Web Browsers like Chrome and Firefox making breaking changes to their implementations of SameSite for cookies.

You can try mitigation steps described here:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14996

Comment: Thanks - I think that's correct. I'll look at the fixes until a patch for 3.0 comes out.